# How to update the App Bundle of an App which is in review on Google Play console. By mistake I uploaded a faulty App Bundle now I want to update it

Tags: google-play

Please help. If any Other information is needed let me know. I also fear my app will get rejected. I want to update the App Bundle(.aab file).

Comment: It should be rejected if it is faulty. I assume you can just submit again with a working package.

Answer (score 1):

If it is under review, you cannot change it now. They will inform you in case there is some issue, and if it is rejected, you can update the Bundle later.